# How to allow a group of user to read, write in particular child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My firebase database looks like below:
[image]
I have multiple group and each group has multiple users. I want to allow a user to `read` data from a single group. For example: I have two group(`main`,`main-2`) in above picture. In group `main` there are some user(`user-1`,`user-2`,`user-3`). What I want is that "`user-1` can read data from `main` group only and can't read or write in other group(`main-2`)." How can I do this?
**Note: I don't like to use `authentication`, But if it not possible without `authentication`, I will use `authentication`.**

**EDITED:** structure of a single group[there are unknown number of group with same structure]:
[image]
And rules for each group:

```
"$group":{
  ".write": "!root.child($group).exists()",
    "cd":{
      ".write":"newData.hasChildren(['ccm','dep','fr','ins','lr','ncr','sins','ts','year','crr']) 
        || !root.child($group).child('cd').exists()"
    },
    "$user":{
      ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['bg','email','ext','gr','ht','name','phone','roll']) ||
      !root.child($group).child($user).exists()"
      }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't tried anything yet. I just want to know how can I do this? Currently I am not using authentication and firebase keep showing warning. So I want to make strong rules in firebase

Comment: How would you know which user is which without authentication? Also, can you include the rules you've tried along with a sample query to see what kind of data you're trying to access. Also, please include Firebase structures as TEXT. not images so we can use them in an answer.

Comment: I have added `group structure` and `rules for each group`

Comment: A bit more clarity is needed so let me restate the intent; users belong to a group and each of those users should only be allowed read/write to that group node. Does this mean the users shown in the `main` group should only be allowed to access that node? Or is that node showing the group members and you want to only allow them to access a different node.

Comment: users shown in `main` group are only allowed to read/write in `main` node

Comment: I have tried something and it is working fine till now. just added a rule for each group.
`$group{
read: data.hasChild(auth.uid)
}`

Answer (score -1):

Вместо аутентификации, можно попросить программу генерировать случайный идентификатор для каждого пользователя. Дальше сделать папку с правильным идентификаторами пользователей и проверять каждый раз индентификатор пользователя, который пишет (отсылать индентификатор и сверять его в папке пользователей, чтобы убедиться в подлинности пользователя), (отправлять индентификатор на проверку каждый раз, как элемент данных, затем его удалять), (при установке приложения, получать индентификатор по паролю пользователя)

Translates to

Instead of authenticating, you can ask the program to generate a random identifier for each user. Next, make a folder with the correct user identifiers and check each time the user identifier that he writes (send the identifier and check it in the users folder to make sure the user is authentic), (send the identifier for verification each time as a data item, then delete it), (when installing the application, get the identifier by the user's password)

Comment: Can you write answer in English? I don't know your language.

Comment: I am not understanding what you are saying. Authentication is not a problem. I will use it if necessary. However, I have tried something and its working fine till now